# Alert boxes when validating form in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex, alert

I am writing PHP to validate form data.  **I am trouble shooting my alert boxes.**

This is the bones of my code:

```
function emailcheck ($email1)
{
$regexp="/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$/"; 

if (preg_match($regexp,$email1))
{
    return TRUE;
}
else
{
    return FALSE;
}
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

if ($emailcheck == TRUE){
    //send email
    //various fields etc
 echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Your form has been submitted.") </script>';

 }
 else
 {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Enter a valid email address.") </script>';
    return FALSE;
 }
 }
```

When I test the form for the emailcheck function to be FALSE I get this;

[image: alert]

followed by this:

[image: alert2]

How can I fix this? Thanks

**edit**

I am not concerned with the entire php/javascript validation; I am looking at a specific detail- what am I doing wrong with my functions here? Why is it printing off the alert.. there must be something basic I've overlooked.

There is, obviously, a problem with how I am using the isset function, and the way I am calling in the emailcheck function.

I have client side validation, but am focused on the php validation in this question - so please, no need to discuss javascript validation.

Comment: I dont know php. But I think this line is problematic: `if($emailcheck == TRUE)` as `emailcheck` is a function. May be it should be: `if($emailcheck($_POST['email']))`?

Comment: Looks like you are mixing server side form checking with client side messages and checking. If so, you should decide on one or the other - not both. For server side checking, instead of displaying a javascript box, echo some text into the HTML that will be rendered and perform a 'catch' (`boolean var` that you check for) to prevent further form processing.

Comment: @Skippy I've got several remarks (maybe offtopic ?): **1-** begin to indent correctly your code. You will most likely prevent issues from the start. **2-** Your regex doesn't make sense, you're missing the end anchor `$`, I suppose it's a typo and you wrote an `S` instead ? **3-** You don't need to escape dots in a character class `[a-zA-Z.]` will work just fine. Hyphens should be escaped if they are not at the beginning or the end of the class, so `[a-z-]` will match letters and a hyphen. **4-** What in the world is this `[a-zA-A-Z0-9_\.]` ? I think you meant `[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]`

Comment: @Skippy  **5-** Aside from above points, your regex will fail with many emails, just use `filter_var()` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`. **6-** Be as strict as possible, at least in this case: `if ($emailcheck === TRUE)` note the 3 equal signes. **7-** `echo '<script ....'; return FALSE;` What is this ? FYI if this is not used in a function it will **exit** your script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got some kind of syntax/ quoting error. Backup your file, then binary search A/B by removing or drastically simplifying sections of code, until the symptom is fixed.

You have then found your problem, & can fix it in the restored file.

Postscript:  error may be in the PHP quoting or `<?` syntax -- we're seeing Javascript either being emitted, or parsed by the browser, as HTML.

Try viewing the source & checking what the browser sees?

PS2:  We're also seeing **PHP code** (the `} else {`) being shown in the browser. Your code sample doesn't show the `<?` PHP start -- you've got some kind of error in the `<? ?>` PHP syntax.

By the way, I'm the only person who is actually picking up these obvious symptoms & helping you.

Comment: NO, I'm absolutely not kidding, and with 20 years experience -- when I can't find an error some other way, I go to an A/B binary search. Binary search is efficient, by dividing the problem, to find the section that is the cause.  Now if you don't want to be helped, don't try it. Impolite.

Comment: And if you care to withdraw your -1 on my genuine attempt to help, I'll be happy to take it as a brief lapse & won't downvote your question.

Comment: You've got a `<?` PHP quoting error -- since we're seeing `} else {`, which should be only PHP code, made visible in the browser.

Comment: I have these difficulties with PHP as well.. it's a bit of a muddy & opaque language.  I mainly work in Java with Spring/Hibernate/Tomcat, which are much cleaner & security and errors are almost entirely caught by the compiler for you.

Answer (score 3):

$emailcheck is a variable and not a function. it should be

```
$emailcheck = emailcheck($email);
if($emailcheck === TRUE): /* more code */ endif;
```

IMO I would use the function that goes with the PHP installation.

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "<script>alert('GOOD email');</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('BAD email');</script>";
}
```

[link to php fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ie4-khv)

Comment: can you try something like:

`<?php
function emailcheck ($email1)
{
$regexp="/^[a-zA-A-Z0-9_\.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+S/";   

if (preg_match($regexp,$email1))
{
    return TRUE;
}
else
{
    return FALSE;
}
}

$emailcheck = FALSE;
 if ($emailcheck == TRUE){
?>
<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Your form has been submitted.") </script>
<?php
 }
 else
 {
  ?>
<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Enter a valid email address.") </script>
<?php
    
 }
 
?>
`

[link](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ie4-khv)

Comment: nvm it's in the fiddle anyway. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to change your test in your if statement.

```
function emailcheck ($email1) {
    $regexp="/^[a-zA-A-Z0-9_\.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+$/";   
    if (preg_match($regexp,$email1)) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $emailAddy = "someone@somewhere.com"; //get email address from form here
    if (emailCheck($emailAddy)){
        //send email
        //various fields etc
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Your form has been submitted.");</script>';

    } else {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Enter a valid email address."); </script>';
    }
}
```

Your current statement isn't checking the return value of your function, it is testing the value of the variable $emailCheck, which isn't actually set to anything.

**Edit**

I also just noticed in your regexp string you have a capital 'S' instead of a $, assuming that you wanted to signify the end of the string.  Also, both of your alert() calls were missing the semicolon at the end.  I've tried out this code on my end and it seems to work. I've modified my answer to reflect the changes.  Hope that helps!

Comment: @Skippy I have found a couple other things that were getting in the way of making this work.  I've updated my answer for you, hope this helps you out.